# Cannot read data from subcollection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I want to fetch the status_code of the particular subcollection of the document but I am getting undefined in the console.

**Here is my code:**

```
router.route('/user/:_id/host/:_id/checkStatus/').post(function(req, res) {
var finalList = [];
Host.findOne({
    _id : req.params._id
}, function(err, host) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    } else {
        var count = host.joinees.length;
        var limits = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            limits.push(i);
        }
        async.eachSeries(limits, function(i, callback) {
            var ID = host.joinees[i].userid;
            console.log(ID);
            console.log(req.body.userid);
            if (ID === req.body.userid) {
                 finalList[0] = host.joinees[i].status_code;
                    console.log(finalList+"HHKHJKHKH");
            }
            console.log(finalList+"aaaaaa");
            callback();
        }, function() {
            console.log(finalList + '-------------');
            res.json({
                requestStatus : 1,
                message : "success! Status Code Retrived",
                joinRequestStatus : finalList
            });
        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: are you getting each part successfully? I mean is `host` found? Maybe you fail somewhere along the way.

Comment: @Pio: I debugged but unfortunately the control doesnt comes into the if statement. I am editting the code. Please check.

Comment: But you do log the `ID` and the `req.body.userid`? Or nothing gets logged/empty line (this means you didn't find anything? Did you log the `host`?

Comment: @Pio : the values are logged but they are not matching in the if statement

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If yes please accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are not matching in the `if` statement because they are of different types. My guess is that one of them is `String` (most probably your query result) and the other one is `Number`.

You can solve that by two ways: either you use only the equal value operator (`==`) instead of  equal value equal type operator (`===`) or you can convert your query result to an `Object` e.g if you are using `mongoose` call `lean()` on your query object, then process the results.